# Community Notice: Pending policy changes on the horizon

Tags: discussion

Right now we're (the mods) in the midst of figuring out what to do about our current "identification-request" issue. It's a complicated and deeply rooted issue with with no easy resolution. We're weighing a lot of different opinions and statistical data in order to come up with some sort of solution or compromise. Please be a bit patient and continue with your efforts in closing bad [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) question that don't meet our minimum guidelines, while we try to figure things out. We realize that no matter what conclusion we come, not everyone will be satisfied. Finding a compromise to all of this what I believe to be the most complicated part of about it.

<s>Additionally, I'm looking to find a way to standardize series tag naming. As you've noticed, sometimes we use the romanized Japanese title names while other times we use the English title names. Originally user which ever title had the most search results, typically the romanized Japanese titles are more popular for new series, while older series more well-known series might skew toward their English titles.</s>

We're very inconsistent and I would like to take some times and implement a more consistent policy of for series titles.

Please look forward to these changes are coming soon. If you have any question or concerns or would like us to address an issue that you wish to see addressed, please feel free to leave a post on this thread and we'll try to address it as best we can.

Comment: imo, the opinions should be what *objective* criteria the decision should be made with and then seeing what kind of data mods can get access to in order to determine whether the data meets the criteria. The data the regular users have access to are not enough to determine the criteria I had set myself a year or two back. As I see it, a big part of the problem is that we don't have the data to back the assertions that have been made about this issue.

Comment: i hope that if id requests become off-topic and we should start removing them there is announcement before hand we start the removal. i want to get all the anime/manga/light novel titles i've discovered from id requests before we get rid of them

Comment: It is not a "complicated" issue, and there _is_ an "easy" resolution that would have been even easier if you/we hadn't sat on your/our hands for years.

Comment: It is unclear to me why standardizing series tag _names_ is something that is worth putting effort into, when adding _synonyms_ for series tags ― which is by far easier _and_ more useful to question-askers ― has mostly not happened.

Answer (score 7):

So...in terms of the identification-request matter...

> We're weighing a lot of different opinions ...

What options were you considering, or would this sort of thing be a bit of an overreach to ask at this point?

Comment: I'm Itching to flag this as `Not an answer` :)